# _messagecontext to be use in Push content

Tags: push

Is there an alternative method to know Push is sent and trigger the AmpScript below? This code works fine in email content, but when using it in Push content, it doesn't trigger as SEND.

%%[
IF _messagecontext == "SEND" Then
CreateSalesforceObject(
'CampaignMember', 3,
'cid',@cid,
'ContactId',@contactId,
'Status','Sent'
)
EndIF
]%%